# Can a only-child have siblings in Jannah/Paradise?

Tags: jannah, relationships

One of my friend never had an elder nor a younger sibling and  spent most of his life alone(without a sibling). He wants to have siblings. **So my question is will it be possible for him in Jannah if he hopefully reaches there ?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is Indeed Possible If you get to Jannah. *This is because anything you wish is possible in jannah and Allah The Most Merciful will fulfill all your wishes and desires.*

In the Quranic verses, Allah the Almighty states that any desires of a person will be given in jannah.

> “Therein are brought round for them trays of gold and goblets, and
> therein is all that souls desire and eyes find sweet. And ye are
> immortal therein.” (Surah al Zuhruf 43:71)

Narrated Abu Hurairah:

> "The lowest place of any of you in Jannah will be that Allah will tell
> him to express his wish. He will wish and wish again. Allah will then
> ask him: **Have you expressed your wish?** He will answer: Yes, I
> have. Allah will say: `You will have what you have wished for and the
> like thereof along with it.''' (Muslim)

So You will Get Anything in Jannah even if someone wants an elder or younger brother sister or even a Ferrari **but for that you must try your best to enter Jannah.**